# UWP App crash on phone lock while playing video

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

It is JavaScript based UWP application. Application is listening to checkpoint/resume event as described on MSDN samples. On checkpoint I'm saving state of the application like history. 
How can I prevent application from crashing? What would be the exact sequence of events that occur when phone is locked.

on checkpoint:

```
app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    try {
        args.setPromise(Ax.Utils.delay(1000).then(function (r) {
            WinJS.Application.sessionState.history = {}; //json string
            return true;
        }));
    } catch (e) {

    }
};
```

Debugging from Visual studio using Lifecycle state works well.

Comment: YOu should debug the suspension of the app. This simulates app suspension which is what happens when the device is locked.

Comment: no issues when used VS debugging states.

Comment: Have you tried with smaller size video? It could be stopping the video that hangs the app.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I tried sample stream from player framework which is 5 mins length & that was working well. trying to understand what is not well with stream.

Answer (score 0):

Wish to add answer to my own question.
Application was crashing due to google ads object included in the stream was not well formed that was causing the app to crash. Such as ads array was not handled correctly during checkpoint.